# Angular6 -> Build error

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6

I used to build my angular 5 projects with command:

```
ng build --prod --locale=de --base-href /onlineshopNP/de/ -op dist/de
```

I've updated my project to angular 6 and when I call the command, I'm getting an error like this:

> Schema validation failed with the following errors:
>     Data path "" should NOT have additional properties (o).
>   Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
>     Data path "" should NOT have additional properties (o).
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.registry.compile.pipe.operators_1.concatMap.validatorResult [as project] (C:\Users\martin.kuenz\Documents\Angular\webshop\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect.js:218:39)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\Users\martin.kuenz\Documents\Angular\webshop\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node_modules\rxjs\operators\mergeMap.js:122:27)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\martin.kuenz\Documents\Angular\webshop\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node_modules\rxjs\operators\mergeMap.js:112:18)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\martin.kuenz\Documents\Angular\webshop\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:90:18)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\Users\martin.kuenz\Documents\Angular\webshop\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node_modules\rxjs\operators\mergeMap.js:145:30)
>       at InnerSubscriber._next (C:\Users\martin.kuenz\Documents\Angular\webshop\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node_modules\rxjs\InnerSubscriber.js:23:21)
>       at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\martin.kuenz\Documents\Angular\webshop\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:90:18)
>       at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrSetError (C:\Users\martin.kuenz\Documents\Angular\webshop\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:248:16)
>       at SafeSubscriber.next (C:\Users\martin.kuenz\Documents\Angular\webshop\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:188:27)
>       at MapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\martin.kuenz\Documents\Angular\webshop\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\operators\map.js:85:26)

Can anybody help me?

Thx

Comment: Something that could help: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9994

Comment: I solved this by installing everything that is shown as npm WARN and related to rxjs Observables. I first use `npm compile` to find the error, solve that, then do a clean install of the node modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a fresh ng project using latest angular-cli and compare angular.json with your project's angular.json.
You might be able to figure our the issue.

Comment: I have delete the node_modules Folder an make a npm install and it´s Work. thx

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem when I update from version 5 to version 6. Try with

https://update.angular.io/

This is a utility to define migration steps. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that RxJS is causing problem, can you install rxjs-compat and check